# Forcing setting of active principal user on each entity for multi tenant application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jhipster

I have a multitenant jhipster application with several entities that I would like to associate or "lock down" with the current active user when accessing. I have done this by creating a many-to-one relationship on my entity to the user table.

Querying is handled easily enough by creating a query like so on my repository:

```
@Query("select myEntity from MyEntity myEntity where myEntity.user.login = ?#{principal.username}")
List<MyEntity> findByUserIsCurrentUser();
```

I am looking for a straightforward way to create, update, and delete but force the user to be set on the server side. So far the possible solutions I have come up with are to:

1. Rewrite all the JPA queries in all of my repositories. This seams a bit tedious and I'm not quite sure of the syntax.
2. Actually set the user object on my entity that has the relationship programmatically in the Resource before saving anything. This would require me getting the current login from the security context and querying the user repository. This would require me to inject the UserRepository into just about every Repository and perform an additional query to load the user object. This seems inefficient at best. Example:

   ```
   private final MyEntityRepository myEntityRepository;
   private final UserRepository userRepository;
   @PutMapping("/my-entities")
   @Timed
   public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> updateMyEntity(@Valid @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity) throws URISyntaxException {
       log.debug("REST request to update MyEntity : {}", myEntity);

       User currentUser = new User();
       currentUser.setLogin(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin());
       myEntity.setUser(current);

       MyEntity result = myEntityRepository.save(myEntity);
       return ResponseEntity.ok()
           .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(ENTITY_NAME, myEntity.getId().toString()))
           .body(result);
   }
   ```

So, is there a "right" way to force the relationship to get set (without passing down from the client)? If so, what is it and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Have you looked into JPA lifecycle events like PreUpdate and PrePersist?  You can add methods to your entities to set the user/login.  As for any query involved because the user is a reference - this depends on how you have it mapped. If you don't need MyEntity to reference the user object, don't map it, and instead just map the primary key (hopefully the login value) as a basic mapping instead.

Comment: I hadn't looked into lifecycle events but I like the idea of just mapping the primary key instead of the entity itself.